# Logical deduction in predicate calculus from a reflexive predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove the following argument by means of deduction:

Laa  ∴ ∃x∃yLxy

Naturally I understand the entailment - If there is a constant *a* for which the relation L occurs reflexively, there are some x,y (indeed x=y) between which the relation L occurs.

I cannot seem to understand how to travel from reflexivity to generality, because the next step only allows me to determine ∃xLxx.

If I try to assume the negative and prove by contradiction I still do not know how to proceed after ~(∃x∃yLxy).

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say much without seeing the details of the deductive system you're using, but are you sure that the inference rule that gets you from $Laa$ to $\exists x\,Lxx$ can't also be used to go from $Laa$ to $\exists y\,Lay$ ?

Comment: sadly not because I cannot isolate one a in this system. If i would like to insert an existential quantifier it will apply to both a's. But yes, that is the natural entailment, I agree. 
I managed to prove it by contradiction if you're interested.

Comment: @DorielleLonke  Yes.  How did it work out.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is simple, using two [$\exists \text I$](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7): from $\varphi[x/a]$, derive $\exists x \varphi$.

Thus, we have only to find the suitable $\varphi$; we have that $Laa := Lxy[x/a,y/a]$ and thus the derivation will be:

1. $Laa$
2. $\exists y Lay$ --- from 1) by $\exists \text I$
3. $\exists x \exists y Lxy$ --- from 2) by $\exists \text I$.

---

If you cannot correctly manage the rule with some "proof assistant", you can prove it by contradiction, exploiting the equivalence between $\lnot \exists x \exists y Lxy$ and $\forall x \forall y \lnot Lxy$.

Instantiating the second one twice you get $\lnot Laa$ that contradicts the premise.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but as indicated in the comments the OP's problem was that their automated proof generator didn't implement $\exists I$ to apply to only one among the instances of the term.